# Spiral hoar frost and spiral device around telephone or electric landlines

Tags: electromagnetism, cables, telephone

I live in Germany. 
When I travel by train, sometimes there are cables that run from pole to pole parallel to the train track.

From the lack of insulation between wire and pole, I guess these are telephone landlines, or electrical cables with low voltage.

Sometimes on these black, rubber-covered cables in the summer I see a thick, shiny, metallic or white spiral wound around them for about a metre (3 feet).

It looks something like this sketch:

[image]

When it is cold enough for hoar frost to form, the frost on the cables takes on a spiral shape as well. This spiral hoar frost forms not only on the device, but beyond it and along the whole length of the cable.

**What is the purpose of those spiral devices on the cables?** And why does the hoar frost form spirals?

Comment: The spiral may be there to act as a damper and reduce [Wind-induced oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockbridge_damper).

Comment: This would really benefit greatly from a good quality photograph of the phenomenon.

Comment: @Wossname I know. I only see it out of the train window. I'll try to take a photo of the device, but I'm not sure I'll get the right kind of frost in the near future. It happens at a place where a swamp meets a forest edge where the air is very humid, and only at the right kind of temperature, and I don't regularly travel that route any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly how they are configured, this is probably a *spiral vibration damper*:

[image: Spiral Vibration Damper]

<sup>Image from https://powtech.en.made-in-china.com/product/wbpQcvdJCXYa/China-ADSS-Spiral-Vibration-Damper.html</sup>

From what I understand they are useful on smaller cables, to dampen high frequency oscillation from wind, and cheap to install.

I can't answer the part about spiral frost. Maybe the frost forms on the spiral and is then slowly dragged down by a combination of gravity and new frost forming, helped along by the constant tiny vibrations from wind. It would still remain in the shape it had when it formed.

Comment: Nice, that's the thing.

Answer (score 0):

In the first image, a grounded wire atop a high-voltage tower shows spiral oscillation dampers. This ground cable also contains fiber-optic inside - any curves in the cable must be smooth - the loop in your diagram suggests that fiber-optic is inside the cable that you see from the train.
The second image shows the cable detail where it is routed to a box at ground level. The sheath is spiral-wound. It is likely that frost settles selectively on the spines of the sheath:
[image: spiral dampners]

[image: sheath detail]